# Why has my view snapped to this object?

Tags: interface, workflow, 3d-view

I was messing around in blender when I noticed that my view was snapped to an object. When I moved it so did my view.

[image]

What is this feature and how can I enable/disable it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a feature called View Lock, wich is enabled by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad .</kbd>, and disabled by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad .</kbd>.

You can also access it from the menus like so:

[image: Clear View Lock]

Comment: You enable it by pressing [Shift]+[Numpad .], not [Ctrl]+[Numpad .] ;)

Comment: Yes, that's true

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Fun fact, I hadn't either!

Comment: @someonewithpc How did you figure it?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I figured that it would have to be in that menu, it made sense...

Comment: @someonewithpc You should change your username to sherlockholmeswithpc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16465/discussion-between-someonewithpc-and-giantcowfilms).